# SSL handshake failing

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl, keystore, truststore

I need to access an API with some strict protocols.

I've been given a private key in .pem format and told I need to convert this to .p12 in order to access the server. Managed to do that part and have my .p12 key.

I've also been given an API key and a password. These need to be included in an HTTP basic auth header.

Lastly, the server is running a self-signed certificate in .cer format. I've obtained this cert.

The instructions are to add my private key (.p12) to the keystore and to add the self-signed server cert to the "trust store".

After a couple days of Googling I'm getting nowhere and I'm not able to successfully make a simple cURL command to the server without the SSL handshake failing. I will update with some of the cURL (and wget) commands that have failed.

Can anyone assist with getting me up and running? I'll be running from an Ubuntu box...

Comment: You may want to take look at http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: Thanks, I did follow that blog post.. In theory it's the closest I've come to what I need to do but still no dice...